# conditional panel combined with reactivity in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a shiny app to realize the following effects:

Whenever I choose variable included by `categoryname`, the web will generate the slider (here I use conditional panel) which provides a divider. It divides the selected variable into 2 groups and form a new column added to the original data set.

The web page can be generated now. My problem is:

1. The slider should be hided when I am not choosing the variable in `categoryname`, but it always appears.
2. Whenever I choose the variable in `categoryname`, the page will exit.

The error shows:

```
Warning in max(MT_EG$id_arm) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in input$divider$max <- max(MT_EG$id_arm) :
  Coercing LHS to a list
Warning: Error in $<-.reactivevalues: Attempted to assign value to a read-only reactivevalues object
  75: stop
  74: $<-.reactivevalues
  72: observeEventHandler [/opt/bee_tools/shiny/3.5.1/users/denga2/teal.modules.km/testapp/app.R#75]
   1: runApp
```

Well the attempt to change the max an min of the slider isn't the only cause. When I set it to be fixed, the page also exits.

Here in the code I simply use mtcars dataset so that all of you can get access to.

```
library(shiny)

categoryname = c("mpg_group", "disp_group")
MT_EG = mtcars[,1:5]

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Mtcars Data"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(

         selectInput(inputId = "arm",
                     label = "ARM VARIABLE",
                     choices = c("mpg_group", "cyl", "disp_group", "hp", "drat"),
                     selected = "cyl"),

         conditionalPanel(
           condition = "categoryname.includes(input.arm)",
           #condition = "categoryname == input.arm",

           #optionalSliderInputValMinMax("divider", "divide slider", c(50,0,100), ticks = FALSE)
           sliderInput("divider", "divide slider", 0, 100, 50)
         )
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         uiOutput("data")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

   observeEvent(
     input$arm,
     {
     if (input$arm %in% categoryname){
       # start over and remove the former column if exists
       MT_EG = MT_EG[, !(colnames(MT_EG) %in% input$arm)]

       id_arm_var <- input$arm
       id_arm <- unlist(str_split(id_arm_var,'_'))[1]

       # change the range of the slider
       input$divider$max = max(MT_EG$id_arm)
       input$divider$min = min(MT_EG$id_arm)

       # generate a new column and bind
       divi <- data.frame(id_arm_var = MT_EG$id_arm>input$divider)
       divi$id_arm_var[divi$id_arm_var==TRUE] <- paste0(id_arm_var, " Larger")
       divi$id_arm_var[divi$id_arm_var==FALSE] <- paste0(id_arm_var, " Smaller")
       MT_EG <- cbind(MT_EG,divi)
     }

   output$data=renderTable(MT_EG)
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any ideas? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors.

`id_arm` is not the name of a column of `MT_EG`. This a variable which contains a string, and this string is the name of a column of `MT_EG`. So you have to do `MT_EG[[id_arm]]` instead of `MT_EG$id_arm`.

You cannot update the slider by doing `input$divider$max = max(MT_EG$id_arm)`. See `?updateSliderInput` to update a slider.

`condition = "categoryname.includes(input.arm)"` is not correct. There's no variable `categoryname` in the JavaScript side. Instead, you can do:

```
condition = "input.arm == 'mpg_group' || input.arm = 'disp_group'"
```

Answer (score 1):

`MT_EG$id_arm` is not valid R syntax espially id_arm a variable contains the column name, to do a such call use `MT_EG[[id_arm]]` or `MT_EG[,id_arm]`. In `MT_EG[,id_arm]` becareful with drop=FASLE and drop=TRUE. 
Use `updateSliderInput` to update Sliderinput during the seesion.

```
library(shiny)

  categoryname = c("mpg_group", "disp_group")
  MT_EG = mtcars[,1:5]

  # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
  ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Mtcars Data"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 50,
                    value = 30),

        selectInput(inputId = "arm",
                    label = "ARM VARIABLE",
                    choices = c("mpg_group", "cyl", "disp_group", "hp", "drat"),
                    selected = "cyl"),
        conditionalPanel(
          #condition = "categoryname.includes(input.arm)",
          condition = "input.arm == 'disp_group' | input.arm == 'mpg_group'",

          sliderInput("divider", "divide slider", 0, 100, 50)
        )
      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("distPlot"),
        uiOutput("data")
      )
    )
  )

  # Define server logic required to draw a histogram
  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- MT_EG[, 1] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })

    observeEvent(
      input$arm,
      {
        if (input$arm %in% categoryname){
          #browser()
          # start over and remove the former column if exists
          MT_EG = MT_EG[, !(colnames(MT_EG) %in% input$arm)]

          id_arm_var <- input$arm
          id_arm <- unlist(str_split(id_arm_var,'_'))[1]

          # change the range of the slider
          #input$divider$max = max(MT_EG$id_arm)
          val <- input$divider
          mx = max(MT_EG[[id_arm]])
          mn = min(MT_EG[[id_arm]])
          updateSliderInput(session, inputId = "divider", min=floor(mn/2),max = mx + 4,step = 1,value = (mn+1)%%2 + 1)
          #input$divider$min = min(MT_EG$id_arm)

          # generate a new column and bind
          #divi <- data.frame(id_arm_var = MT_EG$id_arm>input$divider)
          divi <- data.frame(id_arm_var = MT_EG[[id_arm]]>input$divider)
          divi$id_arm_var[divi$id_arm_var==TRUE] <- paste0(id_arm_var, " Larger")
          divi$id_arm_var[divi$id_arm_var==FALSE] <- paste0(id_arm_var, " Smaller")
          MT_EG <- cbind(MT_EG,divi)
        }

        output$data=renderTable(MT_EG)
      })
  }

  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

## Update

```
  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- MT_EG[, 1] 
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })

    data <- reactiveValues()

    observeEvent(
      input$arm,
      {
        if (input$arm %in% categoryname){
          #browser()
          # start over and remove the former column if exists
          MT_EG = MT_EG[, !(colnames(MT_EG) %in% input$arm)]

          id_arm_var <- input$arm
          id_arm <- unlist(str_split(id_arm_var,'_'))[1]

          data$armv <- id_arm_var
          data$arm <- id_arm
          # change the range of the slider
          #input$divider$max = max(MT_EG$id_arm)
          val <- input$divider
          mx = max(MT_EG[[id_arm]])
          mn = min(MT_EG[[id_arm]])
          updateSliderInput(session, inputId = "divider", min=floor(mn/2),max = mx + 4,step = 1,value = (mn+1)%%2 + 1)
          #input$divider$min = min(MT_EG$id_arm)

          # generate a new column and bind
          #divi <- data.frame(id_arm_var = MT_EG$id_arm>input$divider)

        }
      })

  df_final <- reactive({
    req(data$armv, data$arm) #Do not start process data$armv and data$arm unless they are available. To prevent unnecessary Error messages
    id_arm_var <- data$armv
    id_arm <- data$arm
      divi <- data.frame(id_arm_var = MT_EG[[id_arm]]>input$divider)
      divi$id_arm_var[divi$id_arm_var==TRUE] <- paste0(id_arm_var, " Larger")
      divi$id_arm_var[divi$id_arm_var==FALSE] <- paste0(id_arm_var, " Smaller")
      MT_EG <- cbind(MT_EG,divi)
    })

    output$data=renderTable(df_final())

  }
```

Comment: Sorry I have another question. The code works now but it seems that the value of  the column added to the data set doesn't change according to the divider, but the initial value we set. So like, if I choose mpg_group, no matter how I drag the slider, all the values show "mpg_group Smaller".

Comment: @Dianafreedom it's difficult to help without I know your final goal, but I hope I got you right. Use `reactive` and `reactiveValues` whenever you need your App to response to the user inputs. Try not to do any calculations inside render* and try to keep them outside `observeEvent` whenever it's possible.

Comment: problem solved! Thank you so much. just change the `value` in the `updateSliderInput` to be flexible. Yeah I want to make the output data set change according to my slider.